# K-Means clustering between columns in dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to perform k-means clustering on a pandas dataset I have.

The dataset goes as follows:

```
Index        A    B    C    D    E
01-01.2000
01:00:00     1    1    1    1    2
01-01-2000
02:00:00     0    1    2    3    0.68
01-01-2000
03:00:00     0.58 2    4    0    0.72
```

The index columns goes for 1 years in hourly basis, and I have total of 33 columns.

What I want to do is, I wanna perform a kmeans clustering analysis between columns, which will include every row as a time series. I am expecting an output as follows:

Cluster1: Columns A D G

Cluster2: Columns B C E

Cluster3: Columns I J K

With a total of 7 clusters.

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=7)
kmeans = kmeans.fit(X)
labels = kmeans.predict(X)
Centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
C = Centers
X=X.values
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
ax.plot(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2],X[:, 3],...till 33,marker='o')
ax.plot(C[:, 0], C[:, 1], C[:, 2],C[:, 3],...till 33, marker='o')
```

However after I run the above code, I get the following graph, which is not the output I am intended to generate, since it does not show total of 7 clusters

[image: Output]

I noticed in 'labels' variable, I have total of 8760 rows and 1 column, which I think indicated my approach considers every row independent, rather than considering rows as time series clustering it column by column.

Is there anyway by k-means clustering I can get the output I want? or should I consider other clustering approaches?

Comment: How is X defined? X should be an array of shape (n_samples, n_features). You may want to transpose X before as it seems that the columns of X correspond to your different time series.

Comment: @Kefeng91, I tried the approach, however in that way the C matrix has a size of 7 to 8760. I think this does not make sense, since there will be 7 clusters,therefore 7 centers